# PHP поиск в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Дан список студентов, необходимо сделать выборку и вывести список студентов которые проживают в общежитии и получают стипендию.
Как искать значение "общежитие" и "стипендия есть" в многомерном массиве?

> Иванов Иванов Иванович, мужской, дома, стипендия есть
>   Федосеев Фёдор
>   Авксентьевич, мужской, общежитие, стипендия есть
>   Евсеев Авксентий
>   Яковович, мужской, общежитие, стипендии нет
>   Зиновьев Владлен
>   Иринеевич, мужской, общежитие, стипендии нет
>   Суворова Ирина
>   Аркадьевна, женский, дома, стипендии нет
>   Дьячкова 
>   Лидия Гордеевна,
>   женский, общежитие, стипендия есть

```
    $input_file_name = "input.txt";
    $input = file($input_file_name);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($input as $strings_input)
    {
        $Split_input[$i++] = preg_split("/[\s,\?\.]+/", $strings_input);
    }
```

Comment: У вас не многомерный массив, у вас файл текстовый!

Comment: Так сделайте такой же перебор только  $Split_input массива и проверяйте значения [2] и [3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если разделители `,` можно без регулярок, просто `explode` использовать

```
$input_file_name = "input.txt";
$input = file($input_file_name);
foreach ($input as $strings_input) {
    $data = explode(',', $strings_input);
    if ('общежитие' == trim($data[2])) {
        echo 'успех-1';
    }
    if ('стипендия есть' == trim($data[3])) {
        echo 'успех-2';
    }

}
```

Comment: Можно добавить trim т.к. пробелы могут дать сбой

Comment: @RuslanSemenov согласен

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov первый индекс в массиве 0. исправьте ответ: `if('общежитие' == trim($data[2])` и `if ('стипендия есть' == trim($data[3]))`

Comment: @Alex индексы поправил, без реального тестирования сложно ориентироваться

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант, аналогичен предыдущему почти.

```html
    $input_file_name = "input.txt";
    $input = file($input_file_name);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($input as $strings_input)
    {
        $Split_input[$i++] = split(",", $strings_input);
    }


    foreach ($Split_input as $value) {

      if (trim($value[2]) == 'общежитие')
      {
        echo "<pre>", var_dump($value), "</pre>";
      }

      // if (trim($value[3]) == 'стипендия есть')
      // {
      //   echo "<pre>", var_dump($value), "</pre>";
      // }
    }
```